# POST 400 Firebase API

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, post, http-status-code-400

i am trying to make a Signup page using React and Firebase.
\AuthContacs.js
`

```
function signup(email, password) {
    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }
```

`\\Signup.js`

```
await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
```

`
and i keep getting this error

```
index.ts:118          POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY 400
```

i tried to make sure i have the Correct API and correct format but no chance

Answer (score 0):

From the inclusion of this in the error message:

```
key=process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY
```

It looks like the process isn't actually reading the environment variable for the `REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY`, and end up including the *key* rather than its **value** in the URL.

It's hard to say why this happens from the information you shared, but you'll want to see how your environment variable are read, and whether they show the correct value when you log them.